# Send MMS with Photo via html link in android

Tags: android, html, camera

I am wondering if its possible to have someone click on a link in a browser on android, and it will make a camera pop up so you can capture a image then send it via mms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. Just have the link be something that one of the components in your manifest has an intent filter set for. So for instance, lets say you have an activity called MyActivity. Then the following would go in the manifest:

```
        <activity name="MyActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="special.url.from/your/webpage"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

My activity then directs them to take a picture and send it via MMS.